# Catching onSelectionChange in the frontend side for a Google Sheets add-on

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets, I have an add-on that consists of two parts backend `code.gs` and frontend `index.html`, where the index.html is a sidebar shown upon a click in the menu.
Here is `code.gs`:

```js
function onOpen() {
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    .createMenu('My add-on')
    .addItem('Test', 'openSideBar')    
    .addToUi();
}

function onSelectionChange(e) {
  Logger.log("Selection changed ");     
}

function openSideBar() {
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index');
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

function getCurrentSelection() {
  var currentCell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();

  return { column: currentCell.getColumn(), row: currentCell.getRow() };
}
```

Here is the documentation for [onSelectionChange](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onselectionchangee). The `Logger.log("Selection changed")` is indeed called when the selection is change. But, I need to notify or make a change in the frontend side when the user clicks on a cell and changes the selection.

Here is the `index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <base target="_top">
</head>
<body>
    Test
    <input type="text" id="formula" />
    <script>
      function onSelectionChangeJs(e) {
        document.getElementById("formula").value = e ; 
      }

      function loadCell() {
        google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(onSelectionChangeJs).getCurrentSelection(); 
      }
    </script>
    <button onclick="loadCell()">Get cell</button>
</body>
</html>
```

While currently I am checking the current selection upon a button click, I need `onSelectionChangeJs` to get called automatically when a selection is changed in the sheet.

I believe it's a common need for an add-on development. So does anyone know how to let `onSelectionChange` of `code.gs` notify `onSelectionChangeJs` of `index.html`?

Comment: the onSelectionChange trigger only triggers this function `function onSelectionChange(e) {
  Logger.log("Selection changed ");     
}` You will have to save that event somewhere and your javascript will have to poll for it.

Comment: Is there a solution other than polling ? ideally I want to catch the event when it's generated from the fontend in the first place (when the user click on the cell)

Comment: Well your javascript runs on your browser and the trigger fires on the server. So unless you know of a way for the server to send data to the browser without the browser  requesting it then I'd say no.

Comment: Yes I am aware of that. But the event is triggered initially on the frontend by a mouseClick for example. Why I can't catch it directly without passing to the server.

Comment: The clicks for the spreadsheet are not available to your html.  But you don't have to believe me go ahead write a bunch of code and see that it won't work.

Comment: Yes that's because my html is sandboxed in an iframe. but still if google decide to support  the event it can support it using Window.postMessage. Anyway thanks for your response.

Comment: As Cooper said - polling is the only option in your case. You can pull the active cell with a high frequency which will create an "almost direct" update. Given that `onSelection()` is a [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) it does not allow you to create a new html output or call a Webapp. Depending on your situation, maybe you could find a solution with an `onEdit()` trigger? The latter can be installable and thus ahs less restrictions.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like when a user changes a cell in Sheets, you want that change to be reflected in an HTML page, right?
What don't you send that value to the HTML? It would require refreshing the HTML page I think, but you could rebuild with that new parameter. I don't know enough about the add-on to say more.
But if you have a onSelectionChange() triggering Logger.log only. It could trigger a function that refreshes the HTML with e inserted into html id "formula".
You can't change the js directly with the code, but you can write the code.gs that does the same thing as the html js.
Is that in the direction of what you need?

Comment: Actually that's what I tried in the first place. But Google prohibit showing sidebar on events such as `OnEdit` , `onSelectionChange`. although creating custom trigger can solve the problem for `onEdit` but not for `onSelectionChange`. anyway refreshing the whole html upon onSelectionChange is not favorable, in addition there is a significant time between the server action and the sheet response. Quoting the google team in the issue tracker:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/69238694#comment38